# Hide php table unless it is called through search

Tags: php, sql

I currently have a page where it displays data from my database in tables and it also searchable using some key terms. What I want to do is for the table to be hidden unless it is being searched. I have rephrased my codes because this is an assignment and i dont want it to be picked up as plagiarism. I really hope someone knows a way to do this

```
<?php
  include_once('connection.php');

  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM `players`";

  if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search_word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_bar']);
    $SQL .= " WHERE player_id LIKE '%{$search_word}%'";
    $SQL .= " or player_name LIKE '%{$search_word}%'";
  }

  $SQL .= 'group by player_id, player_name order by player_id ASC';

  if( !( $SQLRes = mysql_query( $SQL ) ) ){
    echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();
  }else{
    if( mysql_num_rows( $SQLRes )==0 ){
      echo '<tr><td colspan="1">No results </td></tr>';
    }else{
      $current_player_id = false;
      while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $SQLRes ) ){
        if ($row['player_id'] !=$current_player_id) {
          if ($current_player_id !== false)
             echo '</table>';
          echo '
                <h4>'.$row['player_id'].'</h4>

                <table style = "width: 100%" class="listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width: 50%">Player Name</th>
                  </tr>';

          $current_player_id = $row['player_id'];
        }
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['player_name'].'</td>
                <td><a href =delete.php?del='.$row['player_id'].'><strong>DELETE<strong/></a></td>
             </tr> ';
      }
    }
    echo '</table>';

?>
</table>
```

Comment: Try not to use MySQL, it is deprecated in PHP and will be removed in later versions. Use MySQLi instead.

Comment: I will look into it. I am just a beginner so hopefully its not much different from MySQL so i can pick it up easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start you open with an if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $search_word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_bar']);
  $SQL .= " WHERE player_id LIKE '%{$search_word}%'";
  $SQL .= " or player_name LIKE '%{$search_word}%'";
}
```

It looks to me like the check for the `$_POST` variable is telling you if you have a search.

That `if` just needs to wrap the whole of this body of code and it should do what you're looking for.

That said, there are a few niggles elsewhere in your code - please take these the right way - in an effort to help and guide...

1 - Rather than build your "like" statements in your SQL, take a look at bind variables.  Also, take a look at `mysqli` usage examples.

2 - Rather than echoing through your code, consider building an $html string up and then echoing at the end.

3 - It looks like you're coding for your SQL select to return multiple instances of the same player.  That suggests either a flaw in the datamodel (the table is called `player` after all), or in the SELECT - why not get back distinct rows.

4 - Echoing SQL errors back to the console is a great way to give external people access to protected information about your system.  Consider logging to a file instead - at least in production.

5 - I've corrected your indentation.   Learn how to use it, it will save your brain many times over if you indent code properly.

Comment: thank you so much Rob,I feel so stupid. I am just a starter and i am still learning the basics so please bear with my stupid questions.

Comment: @Rose There's no such thing as a stupid question here, as long as it can't be answered (as long as you're within the rules on Stack Overflow, which you are).

Comment: Agree with you 100% there @cybermonkey.  Don't worry about it Rose.

Comment: Whoops, I meant 'can be answered'! Wouldn't do much good if no question could be answered (as I said in my comment!).